# Master-Master Mysql-Replication Error : 'Duplicate column name 'my_column'' on query

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I Resync the Master Master replication and got following error.

```
Last_Errno: 1060
Last_Error: Error 'Duplicate column name 'feed_order'' on query. Default database: 'example.com'. Query: 'ALTER TABLE wp_gf_addon_feed ADD COLUMN feed_order mediumint(8) unsigned not null default 0'

Last_SQL_Errno: 1060
               Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Duplicate column name 'feed_order'' on query. Default database: 'example.com'. Query: 'ALTER TABLE wp_gf_addon_feed ADD COLUMN feed_order mediumint(8) unsigned not null default 0'
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
```

Is this error have any relation with this?
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=45470

Or could I skip the following query? Please advice.

Comment: I think that error means you tried to add a column to a table when it already had that column.

Comment: Resolved :)

mysqldump was not working perfectly. had lot of issues. So stopped mysql and  copied /var/lib/mysql to 2nd server and started daemon. And then replication resynced.

Thanks for your help